# Jquery AJAX on A href

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am working on the Jquery A href (used as Button) with button name `Install`.  I've wrote the code for the calling Jquery AJAX file , Ajax file name is `update.php`.

Once ajax successfully executed , I'm changing a href label using.

```
$(.install-blue).text('Stop Installing');
```

Now , I am trying to call updateStop.php. When i click on the Stop Installing (a href). 
Issue is both are sharing same class name, so that it calling `update.php`

Is there any unique way to execute this operation ?

Comment: use id selector insted of class.. like ('#asd')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use HTML 5 data attribute to save the state like for example : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yrshaikh/293nk/)

**Html**

```
<a class="install-blue" data-state="stopped">Start Installing</a>
<div id="msg">   
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".install-blue").click(function(){
        if($(".install-blue").data("state") == "stopped"){
            $(".install-blue").text("Stop Installing");     
            $(".install-blue").data("state", "started");  
        }
        else{
            $(".install-blue").text("Start Installing");
            $(".install-blue").data("state", "stopped");  
        }        
    });
});
```

Comment: In given code it dose not change the data-set attribute

Comment: It does, which is the reason why the above code worked, here is another fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yrshaikh/293nk/1/ check the console.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
$('.install-blue').addClass('fistClass');
```

When the user clicks on install.

Then use:

```
$('.firstClass').text('Stop Installing');
```

When the user click on stop installing.

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5dr4f/1/)

HTML

```
 <input type="button" href="update.php" value="Install" class="install-blue" />
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.install-blue').click(function(){
   var url=$(this).attr('href');
   alert(url); ///call this ajax url
   $(this).val('Stop Installing'); // add this on ajax success
   $(this).attr('href','updateStop.php'); // add this on ajax success
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/rEdEc/) is what you want to do.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.selector').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if($(this).text() == 'Stop Installing'){
        //DO STOP ISTALLING STUFF
    }else{
        //DO INSTALL STUFF
        $(this).text('Stop Installing');
    }    
});
```

});